# How to mock ipcRenderer.on functions inside React functional components

Tags: reactjs, mocking, electron, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing an Electron app, using React for the front-end and JEST + React Testing Library for running tests. I have the following simplified code in a module:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';


const AccountCheckModule = () => {

  const [listingsCount, setListingsCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on('count-listings', (event, count) => {
      setListingsCount(count);
    });

    ipcRenderer.send('count-listings');

    // Cleanup the listener events so that memory leaks are avoided.
    return function cleanup() {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('count-listings');
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Paper elevation={2} data-testid="paper">
        <p
          className={classes.listingsNumberTracker}
          data-testid="free-listings-counter"
        >
          Free listings: {listingsCount}/100
        </p>
        <BorderLinearProgress
          className={classes.margin}
          variant="determinate"
          color="secondary"
          value={listingsCount}
          data-testid="border-linear-progress"
        />
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default AccountCheckModule;
```

Basically, `React.useEffect()` runs once, calls `ipcRenderer.send('count-listings');` and sets up a listener to wait for the response from the main process. The main process responds with a listings count number and when received is used to update the listingsCount state -> `setListingsCount(count)`

Is it possible to mock this listener function to return a 'count' number using Jest.

```
ipcRenderer.on('count-listings', (event, count) => {
    setListingsCount(count);
});
```

If yes, how would you go about achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a unit test solution, I create a simple `electron` module to simulate the real `electron` node module and simplify your component JSX element.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ipcRenderer } from './electron';

const AccountCheckModule = () => {
  const [listingsCount, setListingsCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on('count-listings', (event, count) => {
      setListingsCount(count);
    });

    ipcRenderer.send('count-listings', 2);

    // Cleanup the listener events so that memory leaks are avoided.
    return function cleanup() {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('count-listings');
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{listingsCount}</div>;
};

export default AccountCheckModule;
```

`electron.ts`:

```js
export const ipcRenderer = {
  events: {},
  on(event, handler) {
    this.events[event] = handler;
  },
  send(event, data) {
    this.events[event](event, data);
  },
  removeAllListeners(event) {
    this.events[event] = undefined;
  }
};
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ipcRenderer } from './electron';
import AccountCheckModule from './';

describe('AccountCheckModule', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should render correct', async () => {
    const events = {};
    const onSpy = jest.spyOn(ipcRenderer, 'on').mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      events[event] = handler;
    });
    const sendSpy = jest.spyOn(ipcRenderer, 'send').mockImplementation((event, data) => {
      events[event](event, data);
    });
    const { getByText, container } = render(<AccountCheckModule></AccountCheckModule>);
    const mCount = 666;
    act(() => {
      ipcRenderer.send('count-listings', mCount);
    });
    const element = getByText(mCount.toString());
    expect(element).toBeDefined();
    expect(onSpy).toBeCalledWith('count-listings', expect.any(Function));
    expect(sendSpy).toBeCalledWith('count-listings', mCount);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report for SFC:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58048849/index.spec.tsx
  AccountCheckModule
    ✓ should render correct (47ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |    88.89 |      100 |    71.43 |     87.5 |                   |
 electron.ts |       50 |      100 |    33.33 |       50 |               4,7 |
 index.tsx   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        4.247s, estimated 11s
```

`index.spec.tsx.snap`:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`AccountCheckModule should render correct 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    666
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58048849